# How to use IN in SQL Server with Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT CATEGORY 
FROM PEA_TEMPLATE  
WHERE TEMP_ID = 000001 AND TEMP_VERSION = 2
```

This query returns `'000001','000002'` which is saved in `CATEGORY` column as in this format.

```
SELECT * 
FROM HR_CATEGORY 
WHERE CAT_CODE IN ('000001', '000002')
```

This select is working fine with row string

```
SELECT * 
FROM HR_CATEGORY 
WHERE CAT_CODE IN (SELECT CATEGORY 
                   FROM PEA_TEMPLATE  
                   WHERE TEMP_ID = 000001 AND TEMP_VERSION = 2)
```

But when I use query inside **IN** it does not return any value.

What is the reason for this? Any way to fix this?

Comment: what is datatype of cat_code

Comment: can you shre your table structure. on `sqlfiddle`

Comment: why you are doing this using sub query?? try joining these table
select a.* from HR_CATEGORY  a,PEA_TEMPLATE b where a.CAT_CODE =b.CATEGORY  and b.TEMP_ID='000001' and b.TEMP_VERSION=2

Comment: This is not my actual table and only a demonstrate of this senario

Comment: Are you querying on TEMP_ID or CAT_CODE?  TEMP_ID you appear to be treating as a numeric.  CAT_CODE appears to be a string.  TEMP_ID IN(000001,000002)  is different than CAT_CODE IN ('000001','000002')

Comment: @Leptonator I'm querying CAT_CODE. No wrong there.

Comment: You need to look at your data types of: CATEGORY  and CAT_CODE..  I suspect you may need to do a CAST/CONVERT on CATEGORY.

Comment: Is your subquery returning a single row with the value "'000001','000002'" or two rows?

Comment: @PeterHenell its only a single row

Comment: What is the data type of the `CAT_CODE ` from `HR_CATEGORY ` and `CATEGORY ` from `PEA_TEMPLATE  ` ? And is this the actual query you are executing ? Or there is more ? And how many rows get return from the `SELECT CATEGORY 
                   FROM PEA_TEMPLATE  
                   WHERE TEMP_ID = 000001 AND TEMP_VERSION = 2` query.

Comment: Does your `CATEGORY ` values `,` separated in `PEA_TEMPLATE ` ?

Comment: @CoderofCode values saved as single string `'000001','000002'`

Comment: Then you need to split that string into multiple values [Here is the link how to write function to split the string](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings). Write the function from any one of the approach and then use that in your query.

Comment: @CoderofCode worked fine with `function` and return splitted string in multiple rows. Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If CATEGORY can have concatenated strings with apostrophe e.g. `'000001'` or `'000001','000002'`, then better to use LIKE with JOIN construction, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM HR_CATEGORY 
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT CATEGORY FROM PEA_TEMPLATE WHERE TEMP_ID = 000001 AND TEMP_VERSION = 2) PEA
  ON PEA.CATEGORY LIKE '%'''+CAT_CODE+'''%'
```

Comment: Definitely one of solution for my question, Thanks @cypizek

Answer (score 1):

Your subquery is only returning a single row with the content:

> "'000001','000002'"

For the IN clause to work each value must be separate as two rows:

> '000001'
>
> '000002'

You must split the value from the CATEGORY column into multiple strings. To do that you could use a string-splitting-function. There are many of them out there on the internet, here is a related question and answer [T-SQL: Opposite to string concatenation - how to split string into multiple records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with trimming the values ?

```
TRIM()

SELECT * 
FROM HR_CATEGORY 
WHERE TRIM(CAT_CODE) IN (SELECT TRIM(CATEGORY) 
                   FROM PEA_TEMPLATE  
                   WHERE TEMP_ID = 000001 AND TEMP_VERSION = 2)
```

Comment: I used LTRIM and RTRIM. Nothing changed.

Comment: can't use join??? i already post a comment about it.
see the joining query?? @Nishantha

Comment: what is the datatype of category column and cat_code ?

Comment: In that way also  I have to use IN() instead of where a.CAT_CODE =b.CATEGORY

Comment: what is the datatype of category column ?

Comment: Have you tried casting both cat_code and category columns 

SELECT * 
FROM HR_CATEGORY 
WHERE CAST(CAT_CODE AS NVARCHAR(20)) IN (SELECT CAST(CATEGORY AS NVARCHAR(20)) 
                   FROM PEA_TEMPLATE  
                   WHERE TEMP_ID = 000001 AND TEMP_VERSION = 2)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have `NULL` `category` too. Try to add `AND category IS NOT NULL` to last WHERE.

Comment: Actually `SELECT CATEGORY FROM PEA_TEMPLATE  WHERE TEMP_ID = 000001 AND TEMP_VERSION = 2` return `'000001','000002'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `CAST` on `CATEGORY` in following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM HR_CATEGORY 
WHERE CAT_CODE IN (SELECT CAST(CATEGORY AS NVARCHAR(20)) 
                   FROM PEA_TEMPLATE  
                   WHERE TEMP_ID = 000001 AND TEMP_VERSION = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 go with FIND_IN_SET insted of in
```

i hope this will solve your problem

Comment: I think Find_IN_SET not supporting in SQL Server 2012